# Visual Studio no me deja ejecutar el programa y no crea proyectos!

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

El problema es que al "crear" un proyecto cualquiera, por ejemplo una app de consola, el explorador de archivos no lo reconoce y me aparece "**(0 proyectos)**"

[image: error 0 proyectos]

y ni siquiera puedo ejecutar el programa porque en el botón verde me aparece "**Adjuntar...**"

[image: error adjuntar]

ya he intentado verificando la ruta: C:\Porgram Files (x86)\dotnet
pero sigue sin funcionar en mi caso, no sé si sea un problema de visual studio en sí quizás necesite configurar alguna cosa del S.O. (windows) cualquier sugerencia para solucionar el problema es bienvenida.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este error suele pasar cuando el proyecto apunta a una versión de .net que no está instalada.

Como tu estas creando proyectos nuevos probablemente es problema del archivo [global.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-json) el cual indica la versión a usar para los comandos de .net CLI, comandos que finalmente usa Visual Studio para crear nuevos proyecto.

Este archivo puede estar en varios lados, desde la carpeta del proyecto o las carpetas padres de él, en `c:\users\[tu_usuario]` o en otras, el trabajo es ubicarlo.

Dicho archivo debería ser algo como

```
{
  "sdk": {
    "version": "6.0.300",
    "rollForward": "latestFeature"
  }
}
```

Una vez encontrado dicho archivo tienes 2 opciones:

1. Corregir la versión, por una que tengas instalada. Para eso puedes hacer por consola `dotnet --list-sdks` para mostrar los sdk instalados
2. Borrar el archivo, ya que cuando no existe .net toma siempre la versión mayor instalada

De no encontrar el archivo puedes crearlo con:

```
dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 6.0.100
```

Obviamente usas el número de versión que tu tengas instalada.

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tras buscar y probar varios métodos para arreglar el problema sin llegar a buen puerto lo único que funcionó en mi caso fue reinstalar el sistema operativo. Dejo este comentario para marcar otra posible solución al problema!

Comment: No entiendo por qué has marcado como aceptada la respuesta que te dejaron si no fue la solución a tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

La solucion que le encontre a la primera, fue, en las variables de entorno.

en la parte de variables del sistema, en la parte de path, hay le agregas la ruta de la carpeta del sdk.

Reinicias la pc y listo.